# Detect changes in Firestore db node within client side code

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Could you tell me how to detect changes in Firestore db node within client side code (`.ts` file)? I know how to do that using cloud functions. But how can I do that within client side code?

*Firestore Node:* `projects/{id}/transactions/`

***My requirement is this:*** I need to upgrade provider's(i.e. `projectProvider`) shared property value if there is any change on above node. How can I do that?

***As an example:***

`onWrite` event is perfectly fit on my use case. But how can I implement it inside client `.ts` file?

This is a `node.js` implementation of cloud function. How can I do such implementation on client `.ts` file?

```
// Listen for any change on document `marie` in collection `users`
exports.myFunctionName = functions.firestore
    .document('users/marie').onWrite((change, context) => {
      // ... Your code here
    });
```

***Note:*** I use `angularfire2` with my `ionic 3` app.

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use Cloud Functions for this?

You can use the Web/Javascript SDK in Node to listen to collections using `onSnapshot`. You can also do this using the Admin SDK.  However, the Javascript SDK has a property of the `querySnapshot` called `docChanges`.  This will allow you to filter only documents which have changed and process those.

If that suits your need, I can post some example code.

Comment: I know about the cloud functions and its capabilities. But my use case is different here. I need to update the local property if there will any change on firestore db. So I cannot use cloud functions since that cannot access client properties (`.ts`). Can't we call  `onWrite` event within client code? I saw `call functions` directly method. But it is only for `HTTPS callable function`. @JasonBerryman https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Callable functions allow you to call a function from within your client app.  They do not allow you to monitor changes to your database by another client in the way that Cloud Functions do.  I can post some code that will allow you to monitor a collection and notify you of changes, if this helps.

Comment: Yes, please go ahead and put that. Thanks @JasonBerryman

Answer (score 1):

## A partial solution

The following code will allow you to listen to a single collection.  There is currently no way to listen to sub-collections across multiple project documents.  The best solution to this would be to de-normalise your data model, so that you have a collection called `projectTransactions` and filter client queries with a `projectId` field and enforce access with security rules.

The code uses the `docChanges` method, which allows you to view only changes made to the collection without having to go through each document. This approach is discussed in the ["View changes between snapshots" section of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) when it says

> It is often useful to see the actual changes to query results between query snapshots, instead of simply using the entire query snapshot.

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
require("firebase/firestore");

// Initialize Firebase
let config = {
  apiKey: "*** Your API key ***",
  authDomain: "*** Your Auth domain ***",
  databaseURL: "*** Your database URL ***",
  projectId: "*** Your project ID ***",
  messagingSenderId: "*** Your Messaging Sender ID ***"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

let email = 'my.name@example.com';
let password = 'myExamplePassword';

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log('I am logged in');

    // Initialise Firestore
    const firestore = firebase.firestore();
    const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
    firestore.settings(settings);

    return firestore
    .collection('projectTransactions')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      console.log('Listening to the projectTransactions collection');
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {

        // A new transaction has been added
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          console.log(`A new transaction has been added with ID: ${change.doc.id}`);
        }

        // A transaction has been deleted
        if (change.type === 'removed') {
            console.log(`A transaction has been removed with ID: ${change.doc.id}`);
        }

      });
    });

  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, this is not what I need. I need to subscribe to the `onWrite` event.It seems we cannot do that from client code no?

Comment: There is also `change.type === 'modified'`. These `change.type` properties are the closest that you can get.

Answer (score 0):

## My Solution

**Step 1.** In firestore, make a notification doc for whatever information you want to notify the client side. Something like this:

```
db.collection('notifications').doc('transactionHappened').set({/*your transaction details*/});
```

**Step 2.** Register to your notification doc and listen to it, e.g. when you are writing to a transaction doc, also write your latest transaction info into the transactionHappened doc:

```
const yourHandler = data=>{/*handle your notification details here*/};
db.collection('notifications').doc('transactionHappened').onSnapshot(yourHandler);
```

**Step 3.** Now `onSnapshot` is registered, but if your app was disconnected it doesn't catch any notifications during that period. Let's handle it.

```
const reconnectHandler =()=>{/*you were offline, so read whatever you need from firestore to cath up with the latest data*/};
const disconnectHandler =()=>{/*display something on your screen to indicate it is offline*/};
const monitorNetwork=()=> {
    let status = true;
    const timeout = ()=> setTimeout(()=>{
        if(status !== navigator.onLine) {
            status = navigator.onLine;
            console.log(`Network is ${status? 'up ':'down '}`);
            if (status) { //if network is flipped to online
                reconnectHandler();
            } else {//just went offline
                disconnectHandler();
            }
        }
        timeout();
    }, 1000);
    timeout();
}
```

The little function above will create a heartbeat for you every 1 second to monitor your network status.